# Creating a Solid in Geotools

Tags: java, gis, geotools

I'm currently evaluating Geotools' (version 17-SNAPSHOT) 3D capabilities and stumbled across its `Solid` interface (see here: http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/geometry/primitive/class-use/Solid.html). I found out that I can create a solid by using (among others) this method: `GeometryBuilder.createSolid(SolidBoundary boundary)`. But where do I get such a `SolidBoundary` from? Do I have to make my own implementation of it? Is there any tutorial that I've missed so far?